# Combine two rows into one based on column value in r

Tags: r

PLEASE IGNORE THIS PORTION LOOK BELOW @ START HERE

I am trying to combine the following two rows:

[image]

Into one row like so:

[image]

Here is the code for creating dataset:

```
dataset <- data.frame(Environment=c("PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION"),
                      Green=c("Yes","No"),
                      Red=c("No","Yes"),
                      Completed=c("Yes","Yes"))
```

If `Environment` column has same value, in this case `PRODUCTION` combine the two rows and return the "Yes". I have not included code cause all the code I tried does not work. For example this code takes care of duplication:

```
dataset[!duplicated(dataset$Environment),]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

START HERE - PROBLEM UPDATE

I realised that my problem was not reflective of the problem I am trying to solve. Let me try again. Here is the dataset:

[image]

I want it to be like so:

[image]

There could be lots of other columns. However, all I want to do is if for the same `ID` there are same `Environment` combine them and return `Yes` if any have a `Yes` else return default value. I hope I have worded it much better.

Here is new dataset:

```
dataset <- data.frame(ID=c(15,15,15,16,16,16,16),Environment=c("PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION", "TRAINING",
                                                               "PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION", "TRAINING", "STAGING"),
                      Green=c("Yes","No", "Yes","Yes","No", "Yes", "Yes"),
                      Red=c("No","Yes", "No","No","Yes", "No", "No"),
                      Completed=c("Yes","Yes", "No","Yes","Yes", "No", "No"))
```

Based on @P.Routh code, i think we are a step closer. I have modified the dataset to show that a static signature will break the code:

```
dataset <- data.frame(ID=c(15,15,15,16,16,16,16),
                      Environment=c("PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION", "TRAINING",
                      "PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION", "TRAINING", "STAGING"),
                      Green=c("Yes","No", "Yes","Yes","No", "No", "Yes"),
                      Red=c("No","Yes", "No","No","Yes", "No", "No"),
                      White=c("No","No", "No","No","No", "No", "No"),
                      Black=c("No","No", "No","No","No", "No", "No"),
                      Completed=c("Yes","Yes", "No","Yes","Yes", "No", "No"))
```

With that, I want out put to be like so:
[image]

Modified code below from @P.Routh give wrong output:

```
df <- dataset%>%group_by(ID,Environment)%>%
  mutate(total = n())%>%  #this counter acts as the condition you need
  unite(signature,Green,Red,White,Black,Completed,sep = ":")%>% #combines the columns into one column
  mutate(dummy = "Yes:Yes:Yes:Yes:Yes")%>% #just a dummy column to faciliate in specifying the condition
  mutate(new_val = ifelse(total>1,dummy,signature))%>% #this is the condition
  select(-signature:-dummy)%>%
  separate(new_val, c("Green","Red","White","Black","Completed"),":") #restores original output
unique(df)
```

Comment: Do we need to include a condition to check if environment has more than one values? @LeeS

Comment: @P.Routh that is correct. I realised that my question was lacking. Solution work on one `Environment` value. So I had been working to modify the problem, please see above.

Comment: please see if my solution works

Comment: @P.Routh.. I saw it. I  had to take a walk to get away from looking at the screen. I am testing it right now.

Comment: Thanks @P.Routh and everyone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @P.Routh, @Wen and @eipi10. I took all your ideas and came up with working code that actually work with my large dataset. Here is the dataset posted above and the code that worked:

```
#load library
library(dplyr)

#create dataframe
dataset <- data.frame(ID=c(15,15,15,16,16,16,16),
                      Environment=c("PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION", "TRAINING",
                      "PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION", "TRAINING", "STAGING"),
                      Green=c("Yes","No", "Yes","Yes","No", "No", "Yes"),
                      Red=c("No","Yes", "No","No","Yes", "No", "No"),
                      White=c("No","No", "No","No","No", "No", "No"),
                      Black=c("No","No", "No","No","No", "No", "No"),
                      Completed=c("Yes","Yes", "No","Yes","Yes", "No", "No"))


df <- dataset%>%group_by(ID,Environment)%>% mutate(total = n())#add column total for counter of duplicates

ddc<-df[df$total==1,]#subsets those without duplicates
ddd<-df[df$total==2,]#subsets those with duplicates

ddd<- ddd %>% group_by(ID,Environment) %>% summarise_all(funs(max(as.character(.)))) 

merge(ddc, ddd, all=TRUE)
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

Try this , using `dplyr` and `zoo`

1st method

```
dataset[dataset=='No']=NA  
dataset%>%group_by(Environment)%>%mutate_each(funs(na.locf))%>%filter(row_number()==n())

  Environment  Green    Red Completed
       <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>    <fctr>
1  PRODUCTION    Yes    Yes       Yes
```

2nd method ***from @eipi10***

```
dataset %>% group_by(Environment) %>% summarise_all(funs(max(as.character(.)))) 

#For the detail 
    #'Yes'>'No'
    #[1] TRUE

    #max('Yes','No')
    #[1] "Yes"
```

Comment: I think you could do this: `dataset %>% group_by(Environment) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(max(as.character(.))))`

Comment: @eipi10 thank you ~ SO always surprised me for new thing !

Comment: @eipi and @Wen this seems to work on the test dataset.. I tried the way you did @Wen. However, I did not use `mutate_each`. Thanks guys, will let you know in a few minutes

Answer (score 3):

In base R, you can use `aggregate` like this.

```
aggregate(dataset[-1], dataset["Environment"], function(x) max(as.character(x)))
```

which returns

```
  Environment Green Red Completed
1  PRODUCTION   Yes Yes       Yes
```

---

It appears this question was changed after I answered it. However, a small alteration to my original code produces the desired output (with a bit of row reshuffling)

```
aggregate(dataset[-(1:2)], dataset[c("Environment", "ID")], 
          function(x) max(as.character(x)))
```

Note that this assumes the characters are ordered such that a success follows a failure lexicographically. If the reverse is true, you can take the minimum. Second, in situations such as this, it is easier to use numeric codes rather then text. A second solution would be to convert the text into numbers to perform the above operation.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr`. The key is to specify the factor level for all columns except `Environment`. After that, summarise the column for the `min`. `mutate_at` and `summarise_at` can achieve this task efficiently.

```
# Load package
library(dplyr)

# Process the data
dataset2 <- dataset %>%
  # Set factor level to all columns except Environment
  mutate_at(vars(-Environment), factor, levels = c("Yes", "No"), ordered = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(Environment) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(min(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's not too late. My solution uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- dataset%>%group_by(ID,Environment)%>%
mutate(total = n())%>%  #this counter acts as the condition you need
unite(signature,Green,Red,Completed,sep = ":")%>% #combines the columns into one column
mutate(dummy = "Yes:Yes:Yes")%>% #just a dummy column to faciliate in specifying the condition
mutate(new_val = ifelse(total>1,dummy,signature))%>% #this is the condition
select(-signature:-dummy)%>%
separate(new_val, c("Green","Red","Completed"),":") #restores original output
unique(df)
```

Comment: @P.Routh..you are not late at all. I had to take a walk.. Let me test it out.. it works on sample dataframe I created.

Comment: nice code. However, I think creating static signatures breaks your code.

Comment: @LeeS I agree. The code can be better. I just wanted to be creative. Sorry it didn't work with your original data

Comment: @P.Routh..I appreciate the effort. Gives me something to think about. I looked at this and tried different methods.. Could not figure out how to merge two rows with different values based on a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @P.Routh, @Wen and @eipi10. I took all your ideas and came up with working code that actually work with my large dataset. Here is the dataset posted above and the code that worked:

```
#load library
library(dplyr)

#create dataframe
dataset <- data.frame(ID=c(15,15,15,16,16,16,16),
                      Environment=c("PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION", "TRAINING",
                      "PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION", "TRAINING", "STAGING"),
                      Green=c("Yes","No", "Yes","Yes","No", "No", "Yes"),
                      Red=c("No","Yes", "No","No","Yes", "No", "No"),
                      White=c("No","No", "No","No","No", "No", "No"),
                      Black=c("No","No", "No","No","No", "No", "No"),
                      Completed=c("Yes","Yes", "No","Yes","Yes", "No", "No"))


df <- dataset%>%group_by(ID,Environment)%>% mutate(total = n())#add column total for counter of duplicates

ddc<-df[df$total==1,]#subsets those without duplicates
ddd<-df[df$total==2,]#subsets those with duplicates

ddd<- ddd %>% group_by(ID,Environment) %>% summarise_all(funs(max(as.character(.)))) 

merge(ddc, ddd, all=TRUE)
```

Thank you all.

UPDATE

I thought more about this and realized that I did not need all those other steps in between to collapse rows. If you provide a unique identifier, your data integrity will be preserved eg `group_by(ID, Environment)`. I went further and modified dataset to test that. See New solution below:

```
dataset <- data.frame(ID=c(15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16),
                      Environment=c("PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION", "TRAINING",
                                    "PRODUCTION","PRODUCTION", "TRAINING", "STAGING"),
                      Green=c("Yes","No", "Yes", "Yes","Yes","No", "No", "Yes"),
                      Red=c("No","Yes", "No", "No","No","Yes", "No", "No"),
                      White=c("No","No", "Yes","Yes","No","No", "No", "No"),
                      Black=c("No","No", "No","No","No","No", "No", "No"),
                      Completed=c("Yes","Yes", "No","No","Yes","Yes", "No", "No"))

dataset%>% group_by(ID,Environment) %>% summarise_all(funs(max(as.character(.))))
```